# Using aggregation with post calculated field

Tags: django

I have a field in a model that will be calculated based on two values. The problem now all my code is done using manual `SUM` or `AVG`

What I am trying to do is to have another way to design the model, and in the same time keep the same logic. The main reason I want to do this, because I need to take advantage of the djagno aggregate and annotate functions. Also, to calculate these values in the database side not in Python.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(....)
    ..
    salary = models.FloatField(....)

class Benefit(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee')

    # this field can be
    # Percentage (ex %2 from employee main salary)
    # Fixed Price (ex $150)
    # days
    calculation_type = thetopchoices(FIX,PER,DAYS)

    # this field should be the value 
    # of the percentage or the fixed amount
    custom = models.PositiveIntegerField(....)
```

So basically, I have method that will check the calculation type and based on it I get the amount of the benefit.

```
def calculate(self):
    if self.calculation_type == 'PER':
        return self.employee.salary * self.custom
    elif self.calculation_type == 'FIX':
        return self.custom
    else
        return ( self.employee.salary / 30 ) * self.custom

@property
def amount(self):
    return self.calculate()
```

Now the problem how to calculate the total of benefits for each employee. The best solution is to do the calculation in the database by using Django aggregation. However, using this design will never works because Django need the amount to be a real field.

My solution so far, but I don't think it's efficient.

```
def get_total_amount_of_benefits(self):
    total = 0
    for b in employee.benefit_set.all():
        total += b.amount

    return total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should redefine the `Benefit` model, add `amount` field which will be automatically calculated based on `calculation_type` and `custom` fields value in model `save`:

```
class Benefit(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee')

    # this field can be
    # Percentage (ex %2 from employee main salary)
    # Fixed Price (ex $150)
    # days
    calculation_type = thetopchoices(FIX,PER,DAYS)

    # this field should be the value 
    # of the percentage or the fixed amount
    custom = models.PositiveIntegerField(....)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(...., editable=False) # auto calculated field in save

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Benefit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_calc_type = self.calculation_type
        self.__original_custom = self.custom

    def calculate(self):
        employee = self.employee
        if self.calculation_type == 'PER':
            amount = employee.salary * self.custom
        elif self.calculation_type == 'FIX':
            amount = self.custom
        else
            amount = ( employee.salary / 30 ) * self.custom
        return amount

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        recalculate = kwargs.pop('recalculate', False)
        if self.__original_calc_type != self.calculation_type or self.__original_custom != self.custom or recalculate:
            self.amount = self.calculate()
        super(Benefit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_calc_type = self.calculation_type
        self.__original_custom = self.custom
```

Now to get the amount of all benefits is easy:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    ...

    @property
    def benefits_amount(self):
        d = self.benefit_set.aggregate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))
        return d['total_amount'] if d['total_amount'] else 0
```

If you want to update the benefits later based on any criteria you have, you need to do it like this:

```
for benefit in employee.benefit_set.all():
    benefit.save(recalculate=True)
```

Comment: THANKS.. I thought of this while I was coding, but the problem is I want to keep the percentage there, so when the employee gets a promotion and has benefits = percentage. I need to re calculate those benefits based on the new salary. Are you suggesting that I create an update method and call it after each promotion?

Comment: what is percentage? where is percentage?

Comment: Percentage (ex %2 from employee main salary) .. This should increase when the employee gets a promotion. If the amount is pre calculated I will get it based on the employee salary while saving the model. And when the employee gets a promotion. The amount will keep the same. So your idea is good, I just need to update all the benefits models after any promotion or change in the salary.

Comment: Yes you need to, I have update my answer. By default if you change `calculation_type` or `custom` value for a benefit it will automatically calculate amount, if later based on other criteria you need to update the benefit just call `benefit.save()` with `recalculate=True` parameter e.g. `benefit.save(recalculate=True)` this will recalculate the amount no matter if `calculation_type` or `custom` is changed or not.